# jqplot resize chart when resizing browser

Tags: jqplot

Is there an easy way to auto-resize a jqplot chart when resizing the browser? I have been looking on Google, and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Resizing jqplots is discussed [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/resizablePlot.html).

To make it work when the browser is resized, bind the replot function up with the window.resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
      plot1.replot( { resetAxes: true } );
});
```

Running code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var plot1 = $.jqplot ('container', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]], {});
    
    $(window).resize(function() {
          plot1.replot( { resetAxes: true } );
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.css">
     
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Yea this should do +1. In my resize method I also add the below code - just before I call the `replot()`. This way I make sure the `barWidth` will also be rescaled.
                        `$.each(plot.series, function(index, series) { 
                            series.barWidth = undefined; 
                        }); `

Comment: [Sample showing the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/RNPxQ/22/) [Sample showing the solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/RNPxQ/21/)

Comment: @Mark The fiddle doesn't display anything.  I added all the jqplot files from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqPlot that are embedded in the html of the fiddle and still nothing displays.  Can you or someone tell me how to render the fiddle to see the solution?.

Comment: @Chris22, see updates to question.  Moved the example code into a stack snippet.

Comment: @Mark thanks. I read that article already and that solution is not what I need.  I was hoping to be able to have the pie chart and the legend in separate columns for responsive flow on resize.  (the legend to stack vertically under the pie chart on resize).  But it doesn't appear possible.  I can't put the legend in a column of it's own.

Answer (score 5):

I've found that using replot doesn't always give consistent results if you've got a lot of options on your graphs.  The only way I've found to have complex graphs cope with window resizes is to get brutal and destroy it and rebuild it.

```
function () {

    var plot;

    var renderGraph = function() {
        plot = $.jqplot('chartId', yourChartData, yourChartOptions);
    }

    renderGraph();

    var resizeGraph = function() {
        if (plot)
            plot.destroy();
        renderGraph();
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeGraph();
    });
}
```

Comment: this method worked so much better than attempting to change the size using replot. Sure, we're using a little more resources but it's definitely consistent. Hats off to @Giles